# Intercept and pre-process jQuery-ui autocomplete data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a Jquery UI autocomplete code that grabs data from an ajax request, as i grab the data the results are already put in the input box where the autocomplete is attached. my problem is i have a other data along the data that will be posted with the result of the autocomplete.

I had tried to grab all the i need and put it in a single string with delimeters so i can split() it on the client-side. I want to save the other data in a hidden text field

here is my code

```
    <div id="01ac091c834d81b41f0ef4b6eb09cde90bb9aa1a" style="display:none" title="Add Member">
        Type the name of the member
        <br>
        <br>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <input type="text" id="txtUserFind" size="35">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hidtxtUserFind-nickname">
        <input type="hidden" id="hidtxtUserFind-userhash">
        <input type="hidden" id="hidtxtUserFind-picture">
        <input type="hidden" id="hidtxtUserFind-sex">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    head(function() {


        $(":button:contains('Select User')").attr("disabled","disabled").addClass("ui-state-disabled");

        $("#txtUserFind").keydown(function(){
            $(":button:contains('Select User')").attr("disabled","disabled").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
        });


        $("#txtUserFind").change(function(){

        var userdetails = $("#txtUserFind").val().split(";");
        alert($("#txtUserFind").val());

        /*
        0  profiles.nickname,
        1  profiles.firstname,
        2  profiles.surname,
        3  users.user_hash,
        4  profiles.sex,
        5  profiles.picture
        */

        $("input#hidtxtUserFind-nickname").val(userdetails[0]);
        $("input#txtUserFind").val(userdetails[1] + " " + userdetails[2]);
        $("input#hidtxtUserFind-userhash").val(userdetails[3].replace("u-",""));
        $("input#hidtxtUserFind-sex").val(userdetails[4]);
        if(userdetails.length > 5){
            $("input#hidtxtUserFind-picture").val(userdetails[5]);
        }   

        });

        $("<?php echo $tagmemberbtn; ?>").click(function(){
            $("#01ac091c834d81b41f0ef4b6eb09cde90bb9aa1a").dialog({
                modal:true,
                resizable: false,
                height:250,
                width:400,
                hide:"fade",
                open: function(event, ui){
                    searchdone = false;
                    $(":button:contains('Select User')").attr("disabled","disabled").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
                },
                beforeClose: function(event, ui){
                    $("#txtUserFind").val("");
                },
                buttons:{
                    "Select User":function(){
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Close":function(){ 
                        searchdone = false;
                        $("#txtUserFind").val(""); 
                        $(this).dialog("close");                
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        $(function() {
            var cache = {},
            lastXhr;
            $("#txtUserFind").autocomplete({
                source:function(request,response) {
                    var term = request.term;
                    if ( term in cache ) {
                        response(cache[term]);
                        return;
                    }
                    lastXhr = $.getJSON(cvars.userburl+"getusers", request, function(data,status,xhr) {
                        stopAllAjaxRequest();
                        cache[ term ] = data;
                        if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
                            response( data );
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {

                    $(":button:contains('Select User')").removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
                }
            }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul,item){
                if(item.picture==null){
                    //know if girl or boy
                    if(item.sex<=0){
                        item.picture = cvars.cthemeimg + "noimagemale.jpg";
                    }
                    else{
                        item.picture = cvars.cthemeimg + "noimagefemale.jpg"; 
                    }
                }
                else{
                    item.picture = cvars.gresuser + "hash=" + item.user_hash.replace("u-","") +"&file="+item.picture.replace("f-","");
                }
                var inner_html = '<a><div class="autocomplete-users-list_item_container"><div class="autocomplete-users-image"><img src="' + item.picture + '" height="35" width="35"></div><div class="label">' + item.nickname + '</div><div class="autocomplete-users-description">' + item.firstname + " " + item.surname + '</div></div></a>';
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete",item)
                    .append(inner_html)
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You idea is right, you must use a callback as the `source` parameter. I've put together an example here:

[**Demo on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vmvgL/)

If you read the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) carefully it says:

> The third variation, the callback, provides the most flexibility, and
>   can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback
>   gets two arguments:
>
> A request object, with a single property called "term", which refers
>   to the value currently in the text input. For example, when the user
>   entered "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal
>   "new yo".
>
> A response callback, which expects a single argument to contain the
>   data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the
>   provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for
>   simple local data (String-Array or Object-Array with label/value/both
>   properties). It's important when providing a custom source callback to
>   handle errors during the request. You must always call the response
>   callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget
>   always has the correct state.

So here is an example implementation I used in the demo:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/echo/html/", // path to your script
            type: "POST",       // change if your script looks at query string
            data: {             // change variables that your script expects
                q: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                                // this is where the "data" is processed
                                // for simplicity lets assume that data is a
                                // comma separated string where first value is
                                // the other value, rest is autocomplete data
                                // the data could also be JSON, XML, etc
                var values = data.split(",");
                $("<div/>").text("Other value: " + values.shift()).appendTo("body");
                response(values);
            },
            error: function() {
                response([]);   // remember to call response() even if ajax failed
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include a function on select.  Within that function you can access the value and the label of the selected item and process as needed:

```
$('#input_id').autocomplete({
    source:"www.example.com/somesuch",
    select: function(event, ui){
        var value = ui.item.value;
        valueArray = value.split('whatever delimiter here');
        //do what you will with the values
        ui.item.value = ui.item.label; //This ensures only the label is displayed after processing.
    }
});
```